# Why is Pycharm so concerned with the specific style I code with

Tags: pycharm

I've recently started studying Python and my teacher has recommended that I use Pycharm as an IDE. I do like it mainly but coming from java and eclipse there's a few things that don't make much sense to me.

1.)When I type the code, 'print("hello")' it will give me this annoying light bulb saying switch to a single quoted string. When I click it it makes it, 'print('hello')'. This is the worst part, it gives me the light bulb again and says make a double quoted string. I do not see why it does this. Why would one even be better than the other because from what I've read it is just a matter of personal preference and has no effect or potential effect on performance making the warning overall useless.

2.) I studied Java the last 6 months so I was use to coding that way coming into Java. In Java, it's conventional to code in camel case. Python doesn't work that way. Why is this a big deal in pycharm? All other IDEs could care less how you formatted your work. Also other things like to much white space, not enough white space, and no space after "#" for comments bug pycharm and give it that annoying light bulb.

I guess my overall questions is why have an IDE bother with all these things that are personal preference? If I want three lines of white space why can't I without pycharm throwing a fit and putting light bulbs everywhere?

Note: I do like pycharm overall.

Comment: Because coding style is very important with python. Make a code that can be read with ease by other people and by you later is one of python's spirit. So there is a standard for coding in python and it is https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Bulbs are just kind of assistance. They doesn't say "fix me", but "need help?".

2)

> In Java, it's conventional to code in camel case. Python doesn't work that way.

just disable `PEP8 naming conventions violation` in `Editor → Inspections → Python`

> Also other things like to much white space, not enough white space, and no space after "#" for comments bug pycharm and give it that annoying light bulb.

You can configure your code style in `Editor → Code Style → Python`

But pls, respect PEP8

Comment: > *But pls, respect PEP8*

Yes. Please do @JGerulskis.